# Subject area or field?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, british-english

During writing an article, I tried to choose more appropriate variant between *"subject area"* and *"subject field"*. Online dictionaries haven't provided enough information, than I decided just to count results of Google search for each variant: 135 millions for "area" and 1,48 billions for "field", but *"subject area"* is used on some university website. Thus, I'm really confused with this question. Are both variants suitable, is it depends on UK/US kind of English?

Comment: The [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=subject+area%2Csubject+field&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csubject%20area%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csubject%20field%3B%2Cc0) for it suggests that *subject area* is more common.

Comment: @zondo wow, quite interesting tool, thank you. But I'll be pleased to get full answer.

Comment: What is the 'subject' (y axis)?

Comment: @user3169 Some field of knowledge. For example, "This choice is based on specialities of a subject area."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use *subject area*.  Besides sounding like the right answer, the [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=subject+area%2Csubject+field&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csubject%20area%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csubject%20field%3B%2Cc0) comparing the two agrees with me.

[image: ngram for subject area and subject field]

Comment: I meant full answer with an explanation why or where these variants are used. Although it is just my curiosity.

Comment: @AivanF.: I think it's just how the words sound to the people who use them.  I did a quick search for the definitions, and vocabulary.com was the top result for both.  They each had the exact same definition with the same list of synonyms except that each one had the other.